# Getting the count of rows in each category in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

Let me say, I have two tables **category** and **questions**.
In questions table I have few or more questions under the same category and the table has questions of various categories.

I need the count of rows in each category under the question table.

`Category:
+----+--------+--+ 
| id |  name  |  |
+----+--------+--+
|  1 | Type 1 |  |
|  2 | Type 2 |  |
|  3 | Type 3 |  |
+----+--------+--+`

`Questions
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | catid |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | a    |     1 |
|  2 | b    |     1 |
|  3 | c    |     1 |
|  4 | d    |     2 |
|  5 | e    |     2 |
|  6 | f    |     3 |
+----+------+-------+`

`category_count = [3,2,1]`

**What I did to get the count is**,

```
if($model){
        $i = 0; $j = 0;
        $category_count = 0;
        $count [] = null;

        foreach($model as $question) {
            $category_count++;
            if(isset($output))
                if($question->catid != $output[$i-1]['cat'] ){
                    $count[$j] = $category_count;
                    $j++;
                    $category_count = 0;
                }
            $output[$i++] = ['id' => $question->id, 'cat' => $question->catid, 'title' => $question->title];
        }
        $count[$j]=$category_count;
        $final = ['count'=>$count, 'questions'=>$output];
}
```

**My Question is**,

1. Instead of doing it in code can we get the count array using **sql query** efficiently.
2. If not, help me in optimizing the code.

T!A.

Comment: Could you include the tables please? You can use [this](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).

Comment: within `foreach` missing brackets with `if` check and update.

Comment: marijnz0r KTAnj .. Thank you so much for your answers. I am bit confused in choosing the answer as both are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the DDL of your tables, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM category c
JOIN questions q
ON q.catid = c.id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ca.name, COUNT(*) 
  FROM questions qu
 INNER JOIN questions ca
    ON qu.catid = ca.id
 GROUP BY qu.catid
```